# How to decorate an object with another name in draper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decorator, draper

This is the question

I have a Event model and a User model.

An Event has one creator of class User. I used this line in Event model to associate it:

```
belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User"
```

So I can access the creator through this line:

```
event.creator
```

My User decorator has this line:

```
def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

So I can decorate an User object and access user.full_name

But I need to decorate an event, and use "decorates_association" to decorate the associated User. So I need to call this line:

```
event.creator.full_name
```

I have tried this:

```
decorates_association :creator, {with: "UserDecorator"}
decorates_association :creator, {with: "User"}
```

But it throws and "undefined method `full_name'" error.

How can I prevent this error?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that the creator is not nil? Can you post the full backtrace here?

Answer (score 1):

In your EventDecorator class you can do something like:

```
class EventDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  decorates_association :creator, with: UserDecorator # no quotes
  delegate :full_name, to: :creator, allow_nil: true, prefix: true
end
```

And then your user:

```
class UserDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

Then in say the rails console do:

```
ed = Event.last.decorate
ed.creator_full_name # note the underscores thanks to the delegate

# You can also do
ed.creator.full_name
```

In the second example, if creator is nil you will get a method not found error. In the first, because of the allow_nil option to the delegate method in the EventDecorator you won't get an error it will just return nil.